# Chakra UI Responsiveness Not Reflecting on UI

Tags: css, responsive-design, next.js, chakra-ui

I have used Chakra UI for styling a project in Next.js. While most of the styles and components are working as intended, I am having trouble in implementing responsive layout as the style defined does not apply to component on decreasing screen size.

**Setup**

- Breakpoints

  ```
       const breakpoints = createBreakpoints({ sm: '34em', md: '60em', lg: '76.8em', xl: '144em', });
  ```
- theme.ts

  ```
   export const chakrauiTheme = extendTheme({
     breakpoints,
     colors: {
       brand: {
         main: '#fff',
       },
     },
   });
  ```
- Wrapped **`_app.tsx`** with **`ChakraProvider`** with **theme={chakrauiTheme}** prop
- There are three ways of implementing responsive style in ChakraUI,

**1.** Using Array Syntax

```
<Box w={[300,400,500,600]}>
```

**2.** Using Object Syntax

```
<Box w={{sm: 300, md: 400, lg: 500, xl:600}}>
```

**3.** Third one is to import useBreakpointValue() which I have not tried yet

In theory, the styling should work but the changes are not reflecting in my layout.
**Current Implementation**

```
 export const FormInputWrapper: any = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  gap: '1rem',
  backgroundColor: ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink'],
  // The color properties are just to see if any changes appear or not.
  width: ['100%', '60%', '60%', '50%'],
};
```

**In the component**

```
<Box {...FormInputWrapper}>
```

**Tried the first two ways, but none work**

Please, provide insights on what I might have missed.

Thank you.

**Packages:**
`"@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.6"`
`"next": "12.1.0"`

Might be irrelevant but the `_app.js` looks like this,

```
<CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
  <ChakraProvider theme={chakrauiTheme}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
      {/* <CssBaseline /> */}
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </ChakraProvider>
</CacheProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because `createBreakpoints()` is no longer [supported](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/theme-tools/src/create-breakpoints.ts)
You should use [this](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/responsive-styles) instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).